# scalaFX - Titledpane: how do I get the heigth of the content?

Tags: height, deprecated, scalafx

I created a TiteldPane in scalafx

```scala
    val titled: TitledPane = new TitledPane()
```

and put some nodes in it for my GUI.
Later I want to read out the heigth of the content of titled.
In javaFX this would be done with:

```
((Region) titled.getContent()).getHeight()
```

But if I try to read the height of the content in scala with:

```
titled.content.height
```

the height is marked as deprecated and does not compile. I've got a hint to github (scalafx/issue69) that explains why it is deprecated but does not explain how it can be done instead.

Just to clarify: I want to read out the height of the content of the titledpane, not just titled.heigth.
When titled is closed, then titled.height is 0, but I want to know what it would be when it is expanded (to detect when it has finished expanding actually).

So, how can I do this in scalafx?

**EDIT:**
Here is a example that shows the described error

```scala
    import scalafx.Includes._
    import scalafx.application.JFXApp
    import scalafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
    import scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
    import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
    import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
    import scalafx.scene.Scene
    import scalafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell
    import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, ListView, TitledPane}
    import scalafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
    
    object TitledPaneEndOfExpansion extends JFXApp {
      val expandedHeight = new DoubleProperty()
      val data: ObservableBuffer[String] = new ObservableBuffer[String]() ++= List("some", "content", "for", "testing")
    
      stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
        title = "JavaFX: edit after rendering test"
    
        val list: ListView[String] = new ListView[String](data) {
          editable = true
          cellFactory = TextFieldListCell.forListView()
          height.onChange { (source: ObservableValue[Double, Number], oldValue: Number, newValue: Number) =>
            expandedHeight.value = titled.content.height
            println("old height is: " + oldValue.doubleValue() + "   new height is: " + newValue.doubleValue())
            if (newValue.doubleValue() == expandedHeight.value) {
              edit(1)
            }
          }
        }
    
        val titled: TitledPane = new TitledPane {
          text = "titled"
          content = list
        }
    
        scene = new Scene {
          root = new BorderPane {
            center = titled
            bottom = new Button() {
              text = "edit cell 1"
              onAction = { _: ActionEvent => list.edit(1) }
            }
          }
        }
        expandedHeight.value = titled.content.height //set to 400
        list.edit(1)
      }
    }
```

And here is the buid.sbt file:

```
name := "JavaFXrenderingProblem"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "15.0.1-R21"
libraryDependencies += "org.controlsfx" % "controlsfx" % "8.40.18"
// Prevent startup bug in JavaFX
fork := true
// Tell Javac and scalac to build for jvm 1.8
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"
scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

[image: This is the message from intelliJ]

When I just compile with plain sbt i get the compile error-message:

```
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to ... JavaFXrenderingProblem\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
[error]  ... JavaFXrenderingProblem\src\main\scala\TitledPaneEndOfExpansion.scala:38:47: value height is not a member of scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty[javafx.scene.Node]
[error]         expandedHeight.value = titled.content.height
[error]                                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 03.05.2021 11:09:02
```

Comment: Which version of _ScalaFX_ are you using? Deprecated methods shouldn't stop the code from compiling (unless you've turned on `-Werror`). Is the object that you have placed inside the `TitledPane` a `Region`? There's no way for _Scala_ to know that from the snippet you posted. Can you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), together with your _SBT_ build files? [Issue 69](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/issues/69) is closed and makes no mention of deprecation. Is that the right issue?

Comment: Hello Mike Allan! I'm not sure if Issue 69 is right. This is just what intelliJ IDEA reportet.

Comment: I just hope that this is not related to Java8, because we are supposed to use it in our company.

Comment: That's not a deprecation error. It's saying that there's no `height` method on a `Node` object. You need to cast the object. I'll try post an answer showing how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually get two errors when I execute `sbt run` on your code, and I do not get a deprecation error:

```
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\SomeUser\src\SFC\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
[error] C:\Users\SomeUser\src\SFX\src\main\scala\TitledPaneEndOfExpansion.scala:23:41: value height is not a member of scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty[javafx.scene.Node]
[error]                 expandedHeight.value = titled.content.height
[error]                                                       ^
[error] C:\Users\MichaelAllen\src\SOSFX\src\main\scala\TitledPaneEndOfExpansion.scala:45:40: value height is not a member of scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty[javafx.scene.Node]
[error]         expandedHeight.value = titled.content.height //set to 400
[error]                                               ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed May 3, 2021 9:58:00 AM
```

From your code, the `list` value returns the contents of the `TitledPane` instance, `titled`, as a `ListView[String]`. It is this object whose `height` method you're trying to call. Correct?

The primary problem is that the `content` method of `titled` doesn't know enough about the type of the object that `titled` is storing. All it knows is that it is derived from `javafx.scene.Node`. Such `Node` instances do not have a `height` property, and hence your errors. (It's actually a little more complicated than that, but that's the simplest way to explain the issue.)

However, you already have a reference to the object that is the content of `titled`: `list`. So you can replace the second reference to `titled.content.height` with `list.height`. The first reference, in `list`'s `height`'s `onChanged` method, is accessible through the `source` parameter (it identifies the property that changed value, namely `list.height` in this case). So you can replace `title.content.height` with `source` in this case.

I notice that you're using a `DoubleProperty` type for `expandedHeight` in your example, but you need to keep looking at the `value` of the associated types. That's not very idiomatic. If you don't need this value to be reactive, a simple `Double` would suffice (but this would require that `expandedHeight` be declared as a `var`).

Combined, this produces the following code:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
import scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell
import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, ListView, TitledPane}
import scalafx.scene.layout.BorderPane

object TitledPaneEndOfExpansion extends JFXApp {
  var expandedHeight: Double = _
  val data: ObservableBuffer[String] = new ObservableBuffer[String]() ++= List("some", "content", "for", "testing")

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "JavaFX: edit after rendering test"

    val list: ListView[String] = new ListView[String](data) {
      editable = true
      cellFactory = TextFieldListCell.forListView()
      height.onChange { (source: ObservableValue[Double, Number], oldValue: Number, newValue: Number) =>
        expandedHeight = source.value
        println("old height is: " + oldValue.doubleValue() + "   new height is: " + newValue.doubleValue())
        if (newValue.doubleValue() == expandedHeight) {
          edit(1)
        }
      }
    }

    val titled: TitledPane = new TitledPane {
      text = "titled"
      content = list
    }

    scene = new Scene {
      root = new BorderPane {
        center = titled
        bottom = new Button() {
          text = "edit cell 1"
          onAction = { _: ActionEvent => list.edit(1) }
        }
      }
    }
    expandedHeight = list.height.value //set to 400
    list.edit(1)
  }
}
```

Your code then compiles and runs.

**Updated**

*ScalaFX* is simply a wrapper for *JavaFX*: each *JavaFX* type has a corresponding *ScalaFX* type. *ScalaFX* provides implicit conversion functions to seamlessly convert, say, a *JavaFX* `TitledPane` to a *ScalaFX* `TitledPane`, and vice versa. However, there's no inheritance relationship between the two sets of objects. That is, a *JavaFX* `TitledPane` has no type relationship to a *ScalaFX* `TitledPane`. Casting between the two sets of objects is therefore a complicated process.

If you wanted to be able to cast `titled.content` correctly in order to access the `height` property of the contents more directly, you would need to get the property's value and explicitly pattern match on the result with the *JavaFX* version of the object, as follows:

```scala
import javafx.scene.control.{ListView => JFXListView}
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
import scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell
import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, ListView, TitledPane}
import scalafx.scene.layout.BorderPane

object TitledPaneEndOfExpansion extends JFXApp {
  var expandedHeight: Double = _
  val data: ObservableBuffer[String] = new ObservableBuffer[String]() ++= List("some", "content", "for", "testing")

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "JavaFX: edit after rendering test"

    val list: ListView[String] = new ListView[String](data) {
      editable = true
      cellFactory = TextFieldListCell.forListView()
      height.onChange { (source: ObservableValue[Double, Number], oldValue: Number, newValue: Number) =>
        expandedHeight = titled.content.value match {
          case lv: JFXListView[_] => lv.height.value
          case _ => {
            throw new RuntimeException(s"Unexpected content type: ${titled.content.getClass.getCanonicalName}")
          }
        }
        println("old height is: " + oldValue.doubleValue() + "   new height is: " + newValue.doubleValue())
        if (newValue.doubleValue() == expandedHeight) {
          edit(1)
        }
      }
    }

    val titled: TitledPane = new TitledPane {
      text = "titled"
      content = list
    }

    scene = new Scene {
      root = new BorderPane {
        center = titled
        bottom = new Button() {
          text = "edit cell 1"
          onAction = { _: ActionEvent => list.edit(1) }
        }
      }
    }
    expandedHeight = titled.content.value match {  //set to 400
      case lv: JFXListView[_] => lv.height.value
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unexpected content type: ${titled.content.getClass.getCanonicalName}")
    }
    list.edit(1)
  }
}
```

If you didn't have any other means of referencing the `list` object, that would be your only option.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! This trick (pulling out the original javaFX node with match case) might come in handy in some other occasion.